# How to implement a String value into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I created this code in wich I have a String array.The problem is I have a value from another Intent which I want to add to the array.I know it is much easier to use an ArrayList, but the problem is after I have put the value to the array I want to set a random string of the array on the Textview so I use

```
txtV1.setText(myStringArray[new Random().nextInt(myStringArray.length)]);
```

but this is not possible with an ArrayList because it says : The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList

I googled it but couldn't find any solution.
Hope you can help me.

This is my whole code:

```
String[] myStringArray = {"Object1","Object2","Object3"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtV1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("key");//this value I want to add to the array

txtV1.setText(myStringArray[new Random().nextInt(myStringArray.length)]);
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace or error message, as what you show and what you wrote don't make sense.

Comment: In my code is no error. I only want to know hot to put a new value which a user typed in to my array and after that I want my textview to choose one random string of the array including the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using System.arraycopy to an extended array, like this:

```
String[] oldArray = {"Object1","Object2","Object3"};
String[] newArray = new String[oldArray.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, oldArray.length);

String randomValue = newArray[new Random().nextInt(newArray.length)];
```

This leaves the last space free, which you can fill with whatever `String` you want to.

Or, with your wishes and variables:

```
String[] myStringArray = {"Object1","Object2","Object3"};
String[] myNewStringArray = new String[myStringArray.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(myStringArray, 0, myNewStringArray, 0, myStringArray.length);
myNewStringArray[myNewStringArray.length - 1] = extras.getString("key");

txtV1.setText(myNewStringArray[new Random().nextInt(newArray.length)]);
```

Though if you see any possibility in turning your code around by using `ArrayList`, I'd strongly recommend that approach.

**Update**

The same approach with an `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList( myArray ); // Or Arrays.asList("Object1", "Object2", "Object3"); if you'd like to hardcode initial values.
myList.add(extras.getString("key");
txtV1.setText(myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size())));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Though, if you're interested. File another question with the full usage of the array, since I think an `ArrayList` would be an improvement in your case. I'll post a small update how to get the Random from an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList to hold your strings and then use the get(int) to retrieve a particular String or toArray() to convert the list to an array of Strings when you need to.

```
ArrayList <String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add(new String("Object1"));
array.add(new String("Object2"));
array.add(new String("Object3"));

setText(array.get(new Random().nextInt(array.size())));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work just fine for me

```
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
myArray.add("MyKey");
myArray.add("MyKey2");
myArray.add("MyKey3");
TextView myTextView = new TextView(null); 
myTextView.setText(myArray.get(rand.nextInt(myArray.length())));
```

Your problem is some this else,

Comment: Hm could you explain it a bit more? Where you put the value to the array?

Comment: But this display only the value and I want the textview to choose one random string of the array and therefor I can't use an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use ArrayList<> instead of arrays?

```
ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Object1","Object2","Object3"));

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtV1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = extras.getString("key");

    myStrings.add(value);
    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(myStrings.size());
    txtV1.setText(myStrings.get(randomIndex));
```